# Why is my FOREIGN KEY constraint not working:why are the values not present in the foreign column inserted anyway?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I am using the Online SQL Compiler.Even if I insert a StudentId into the Marks table, that is not present in the Student table, it inserts that value without throwing any error.

Why is my foreign key constraint not working? I tried many ways to write the constraint and it still does not work.

My code is:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
( 
    StudentId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FName varchar(10) DEFAULT 'maya',
    DOJ DATE DEFAULT '20-JAN-2021',
    GENDER CHAR(1) CHECK(GENDER IN('M','F')),
    ContactNo NUMBER(10) UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO Student (StudentId, GENDER, ContactNo) 
VALUES (1003, 'F', NULL);

INSERT INTO Student (StudentId, FName, GENDER, ContactNo) 
VALUES (1004, 'Riya', 'F', 9846669343);

INSERT INTO Student (StudentId, FName, GENDER, ContactNo) 
VALUES (1005, 'Diya', 'F', 9846649343);

CREATE TABLE Marks
(
    CourseId INTEGER,
    StudentId integer,
    marks NUMBER(4,2),
    FOREIGN KEY (StudentId) REFERENCES Student (StudentId) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE
);
               
INSERT INTO Marks VALUES (2, 1003, 80.54);
INSERT INTO Marks VALUES (3, 1004, 91.5);
INSERT INTO Marks VALUES (2, 2001, 93.55);

SELECT * FROM Marks;
```

My output is:

```
2|1003|80.54
3|1004|91.5
2|2001|93.55
```

Here StudentId:2001 is not present in StudentId column of the Student table,but it is inserted anyway.Why is this happening?

Comment: It seems your "Online SQL compiler" doesn't really **enforce** the foreign key constraint..... attempting to do this in SQL Server results in an (expected) error: *Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 30 - The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Marks__StudentId__63A3C44B". The conflict occurred in database "master", table "dbo.Student", column 'StudentId'.* on the third `INSERT` line with `StudentId = 2001` ... So I'd suggest you use a **REAL** SQL database engine - whichever it is

Comment: Yes I guess I'll do it in other SQL database engine then.

Comment: Which compiler, which version of which SQL product? What does their documentation say about enforcing FKs? A [mre] includes all that. Please research before considering posting a question. [ask] [help]